# How to group numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create some logic that would calculate a subscription scheme based on the number of devices. The pricing for this thing is a little weird and I've hit a brick wall so let me try to explain it.

The pricing model is like so

1,2 devices is $15 each (3,4,5) is a flat $10(for that whole group) + the original first two devices and then this Pattern repeats indefinitely. So let me illustrate further 1,2 (3,4,5) 6,7 (8,9,10) this comes out to a total of $80 we have 4 devices to be charged the amount of $15 each and then 2 groups that are charged $10 flat each but this also applies if it were 1,2 (3,4,5) 6,7 (8,9,) this still comes out to $80 because the groups start at the first number so 1,2 (3) would come out to $40. So my problem is that i don't know how to accomplish this. Here is my code thus far any help or direction would be appreciated. I also have a feeling i am approaching this from a total wrong angle.

**JavaScript**

```
var numberOfDevices = 19,
    numberOfEach = 8,   //Awesome imaginary code that would calculate the value from numberOfDevices
    numberOfGroups = 4, //Awesome imaginary code that would calculate the value from numberOfDevices
    priceOfEach = 15,
    priceOfGroup = 10,
    addUpEach = numberOfEach * priceOfEach,
    addUpGroup = numberOfGroups * priceOfGroup,
    addUpAll = addUpEach + addUpGroup;

    alert(addUpAll);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call sets of five a package just because we have to call it something. Packages are easy to count, we just do integer division on the number of devices:

```
var packages = Math.floor(19 / 5);
```

It's straightforward to calculate the total for `packages` number of packages:

```
var total = packages * (15 + 15 + 10); // or var total = packages * 40
```

Now we get the leftovers using the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()):

```
var leftovers = 19 % 5;
```

Apply the rules stated in the question, zero dollars for zero devices, 15 dollars each for the first two, 40 dollars for the package:

```
if(leftovers <= 2) { 
  total += leftovers * 15;
} else { // otherwise count it as a package.
  total += 40;
}
```

Wrapping all this up in a readable two line solution:

```
function calc(num) {
  var leftovers = num % 5;
  return (leftovers <= 2 ? leftovers * 15 : 40) + Math.floor(num / 5) * 40;
}
```

An unreadable but working solution:

```
function c(n){return n%5<=2?n%5*15:40+Math.floor(n/5)*40;}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Can i have your brain? I knew i was approaching this thing completely wrong.

Comment: Recognizing that you aren't connecting the dots is a great skill to have. Translating rules to code becomes easier with time. I get that feeling of being lost or not on the right path all the time. It doesn't go away, the problems just change :)

Comment: I feel like your answer deserves to not be lost because i could not find anything similar to what i was trying to accomplish no mater what search parameters i used. Can someone come up with a better title for my question so that it helps others in the future.